# Userform textbox control can't exit using Enter key at the 1st run, but working at the 2nd run in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, controls, userform

I assigned a macro to a shape in a worksheet to run a Userform, but unfortunately I can't exit any of my textboxes inside the form using the Enter key, but you can jump within the textbox by mouse click.

When I exit/terminate the form and run it again, then it will work.

I set a filter to the textbox to search for each changes, and the listbox doesn't work too, but it works on the 2nd time I run the userform.

What could be the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, i tried re-creating what you said but it works fine. Would you share the code that you made. Probably that will help to figure out what is happening

Comment: The code is too long fit in this comment....

Comment: [Identification Form](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VvMccr-Nrd75_D-VB5Mosi7qUW1FrRp8/view?usp=sharing)